# How should I record the script for Java Applet in Selenium?

Tags: testing, selenium

Here is the thing I want to do:

First I want to record the script in Selenium for Java Applet (EditLive) and then convert it into TestNG and then run it in Eclipse.
If you know some other automation tools for recording EditLive and then integrating it with Selenium, please let me know.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, but apart from the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class, which makes it kinda hard to actually do anything, I don't think that's possible.

Using any other [recording tool](https://www.google.com/search?q=record%20mouse) you could record interaction with it, but you can't save it and use it as TestNG test then. But [maybe I'm wrong and somebody actually invented one that can export its script into Java](https://www.google.com/search?q=record%20tool%20java%20robot)...

Comment: Thanks Slanec.
Hey I guess it can be done via LiveConnect...
Here are links for LiveConnect:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LiveConnect
http://fest.codehaus.org/Selenium